# NoClassDefFoundError: HikariCP with Maven

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, hikaricp, bungeecord

I'm creating a Maven plugin (to hook into Spigot/Bukkit/BungeeCord) and am attempting to connect to a database. On startup, I get this error:

```
Exception encountered when loading plugin: WarCore
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource
```

I've tried using the Maven dependency plugin, Maven assembly plugin, but I cannot find a solution.

Here's my current pom.xml:

```xml
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.braden.warcoreproxy</groupId>
  <artifactId>WarCoreProxy</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>WarCoreProxy</name>
  <description>WarCoreProxy</description>
        <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>bungeecord-repo</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
            <repository>
        <id>confuser-repo</id>
        <url>http://ci.frostcast.net/plugin/repository/everything</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>me.confuser</groupId>
    <artifactId>BanManager</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0</version>
  </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.md-5</groupId>
            <artifactId>bungeecord-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.md-5</groupId>
            <artifactId>bungeecord-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>javadoc</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Let me know if you have any solutions, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give more detail about when exactly you are encountering the error?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908170/noclassdeffoundexception-while-trying-to-use-hikaricp