# NoClassDefFoundException while trying to use HikariCP

Tags: java, hikaricp, bungeecord

I'm so noob at external stuff to Bukkit programming, so I'm sorry if it's so easy to solve :P

I have a problem, and it's that when I try to use HikariCP in my project, it returns in an error (the title one).

I'm using it in a BungeeCord plugin.
The weird thing is that I have done this successfully couples of times, and I don't know why it isn't working this time.

The error / log:

```
06:13:36 [ADVERTENCIA] Exception encountered when loading plugin: DiverseReport java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource at net.srlegsini.DiverseReport.Bungee.MClass.onEnable(MClass.java:44) at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.enablePlugins(PluginManager.java:227) at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord.start(BungeeCord.java:272) at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher.main(BungeeCordLauncher.java:55) at net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass0(PluginClassloader.java:53) at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass(PluginClassloader.java:27) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ... 5 more
```

My main class:

```
package net.srlegsini.DiverseReport.Bungee;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

import net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.Plugin;
import net.md_5.bungee.config.Configuration;
import net.md_5.bungee.config.ConfigurationProvider;
import net.md_5.bungee.config.YamlConfiguration;
import net.srlegsini.DiverseReport.Bukkit.UUIDFetcher;

public class MClass extends Plugin {

    static Configuration config;
    static MClass plugin;

    static HikariDataSource hikari;
    static Connection connection;

    public void onEnable() {
        BungeeCord.getInstance().getPluginManager().registerListener(this, new ChannelListener());
        BungeeCord.getInstance().registerChannel("Return");

        loadCfg();

        if (!config.contains("MySQL")) {
            config.set("MySQL.Enable", false);

            config.set("MySQL.Host", "localhost");
            config.set("MySQL.Port", 3306);
            config.set("MySQL.User", "user");
            config.set("MySQL.Pass", "pass");
            config.set("MySQL.Database", "Sr_DiverseReport");
        }

        saveCfg(getDataFolder());

        hikari = new HikariDataSource();
        hikari.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", config.getString("MySQL.Host"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("port", 3306);
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", config.getString("MySQL.Database"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("user", config.getString("MySQL.User"));
        hikari.addDataSourceProperty("password", config.getString("MySQL.Pass"));

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = hikari.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {

        }

        saveCfg(getDataFolder());



    }

    public void loadCfg() {
        try {
            File file = new File(getDataFolder(), "config.yml");
            if (!getDataFolder().exists()) {
                getDataFolder().mkdir();
            }

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            config = ConfigurationProvider.getProvider(YamlConfiguration.class)
                    .load(new File(getDataFolder(), "config.yml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void saveCfg(File dataFolder) {
        try {
            ConfigurationProvider.getProvider(YamlConfiguration.class).save(config, new File(dataFolder, "config.yml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "deprecation" })
    public static String getUUID(String playerName) {
        UUIDFetcher fetcher = new UUIDFetcher(Arrays.asList("evilmidget38", "mbaxter"));
        String playerUUID = null;
        try {
            playerUUID = UUIDFetcher.getUUIDOf(playerName).toString();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            playerUUID = BungeeCord.getInstance().getPlayer(playerName).getUniqueId().toString();
        }

        return playerUUID;
    }

}
```

My procedure:
Create the project, import BungeeCord.jar, HikariCP-2.6.0.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar in buildpath, import HikariCP-2.6.0.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar

It worked in other projects, but magically, it's broken.
I don't want to use Maven, just because it must have a fix, because as I said, I used this same procedure so many times in the past.

Thank you for taking the time to read this :)

EDIT: 
[Image of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vKnJ.jpg)

Comment: Please include the exception stacktrace and your code in your question, don't link to external locations.

Comment: It's done. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

The `HikariDataSource` is missing at runtime, you need to provide it somehow, for example by copying the relevant .jar with 'drivers' into your server libraries folder.

Also see some related questions:
[How to set up datasource with Spring for HikariCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172643/how-to-set-up-datasource-with-spring-for-hikaricp) and
[How do I configure HikariCP in my Spring Boot app in my application.properties files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490967/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-in-my-spring-boot-app-in-my-application-properties-f)

Comment: Nice, but one thing... I know how to use HikariCP, and I was working a long time with it in so many other plugins. What happens is that now, magically, I can't use it.
Also, I tried copying and pasting the older projects. Doesn't works.

Comment: well it may be the case that the database drivers used to be bundled with some other library you're using, but upgrading a dependency removed it from your project.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception it is clear that HikariCP-2.6.0.jar was in classpath during compile time but is missing in runtime and from the image of the project structure, it is also clear that both HikariCP-2.6.0.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar are missing as library reference in the ide. You need to keep these jar in your classpath library during compile time and runtime.

Comment: Nice, and thank you, but... How can I do this?
(I'm so noob at stuff like this, sorry for stupid questions.)

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Comment: I tried with all methods... Nothing seems to work :/